# Can I beat Arnold in arm wrestling?

Tags: bodybuilding, arms, power, forearm

Arnold Schwarzenegger is 66 years old now, and I know you can see all recent videos of him working out, his arm size still is up, etc.

I'm a young guy, 22 years old. I do not do bodybuilding, and workout for strength only.

I feel that I can beat Arnold Schwarzenegger in arm wrestling, and I would like to hear your opinion on whether or not you think I could.

I can currently do this, although not ideal, not too bad:

- Bench press 135 lbs. x 1 rep.
- Squat 135 lbs. x 1 rep, ATG.
- Biceps curl 40 lbs. for single (left; 45 lbs. for single in right), 80 lbs. for double, several reps (about 3-5), dead-hang form (arms hanging completely straight, no jerk, momentum, leaning back, etc.; 100% strict).
- I can do 3 dead-hang chin-ups and weigh 195 lbs.; can't do a single dead-hang pull-up though, but can come close.
- I can deadlift about 315 lbs. max, and I feel I could at least give him a run for his money in a full-on, full-force, no holds barred arm wrestling match.

What do you think? Remember, we're talking Arnold right now, not Arnold in his heyday.

Comment: Lol....I'm not sure if the question should be answered or closed. But on an off-topic note, unless he has a weak heart, I expect him to win. Because he has gone through these routines all his life, he's still stronger *(and more experienced)* than you are and the longer the contest lingers, the weaker you become, and the faster your chance of winning plummets.

Comment: You can curl 40 lbs per arm 3-5 reps? You weight 195? Arnold now would probably wipe the floor with you. He's significantly heavier than you, significantly stronger than you, and has been around the block a few times. Don't underestimate Old Man Strength™. Especially from someone his size and former peak strength.

Comment: But +1 for a crazily ballsy question. :p

Comment: Don't know what's more hilarious. The question or the reason for closing it. Great stuff for a slow going day like today, though.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not constructive for this site. If you say it's off-topic, then why did you even post it in the first place?

Comment: Your bench+squat+deadlift add up to  only 3 times your body weight.  Go hit the gym NOW!

Comment: @LarissaGodzilla I think if the question is re-worded properly, it should be re-opened.

Comment: @Kneel-Before-ZOD: I don't see how this could be reworded properly. Aside from the fact that the OP never actually tried to make the question legit.

Answer (score 5):

Not only is he bigger than you: you're weak, he's strong. You delineate exactly zero qualifications for victory. You have no chance except his charity.

Comment: +1 for the brutally tough love. Stumbled over this nugget by accident. Tell me, why was this answer not accepted? :D

Comment: too funny... :D